# How to set an alias for a specific file or directory?

Tags: bash, alias

There are several files I work with often. For instance some configuration files or log files. Let's say the Apache log file. I often want to `tail` or `grep` it. Instead of writing:

`tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error_log`

I prefer to write

`tail -50 apachelog`

So that `apachelog` functions as an alias for this filename. But if I define an alias in my `bashrc`, it needs to be a whole command; it (apparently) can not be an alias for a filename so that you can reference it later. Is there a way to achieve this?

NOTE: I have a large variety of files and a large variety of different commands I want to run, so creating functions or aliasses for all of those different options will not be my preferred solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a variable, and use a `$` to recall its value:

```
apachelog=/var/log/apache2/error_log
tail -50 $apachelog
```

You're not going to do better in bash. In zsh, you can define global aliases, that are expanded everywhere on the command line:

```
alias -g apachelog=/var/log/apache2/error_log
tail -50 apachelog
```

But I don't recommend it, because now if you ever want to pass the string `apachelog` as an argument to a command, you need to remember to quote it.

Comment: Good answer, especially the "Do not recommend this" part. That sounds like a recipe for disaster with a poor alias name choice...

Answer (score 7):

You could create a function and write your command "backwards"

```
apachelog() {
  "$@" /var/log/apache2/error_log
}

apachelog tail -50
```

Answer (score 2):

An alias to a directory is link. That's why one possibility is to create a bunch of links to the files of interest in one directory. Then alias rtail to tail so that it looks for files in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

For bash aliases, the documentation states:

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Notice the trailing space in the definition of the `tail` alias:

```
alias tail='tail '
alias apache=/var/log/apache2/error_log

tail apache
```

This should work in any standard shell, not just bash. Note that you will not be able to use options to tail from the command-line.

Comment: Note that the user in the question seems to want to provide options for `tail` (and that it's unclear whether these options are static or not).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `~/.bashrc`

```
 alias tailapache='tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error_log'
```

do a `source ~/.bashrc` or start a new bash session...

then you just need to type `tailapache`